# How to run if statement 3 consecutive times?

Tags: java

I want a 1 to be printed if a>m three consecutive times. I have tried running it through a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i<message.length; i+=3){
  if(a>m){
    System.out.println("1");
  }
}
```

I want the program to stop right when it hits the first set where a>m three consecutive times.

Comment: use a counter variable in this if statement. And on counter=3, just break the loop.

Comment: You want to stop the program or stop the looping?

Comment: `i+=3`?  Maybe try `i++`, assuming that `message.length` is `3`...

Comment: how do `a` and `m` get modified? if it is just this loop and no other code apart from this which changes values of `a` and `m` the question doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3):

Add a counter of consecutive hits, which is initially set to zero. Increment it each time you get a hit. Once the counter reaches three, break out of the loop. Otherwise, continue looping:

```
int consecutiveHits = 0;
for (...) {
    if (a > m) {
        ...
        consecutiveHits++;
        if (consecutiveHits == 3) {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        consecutiveHits = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be improperly using your `for` syntax if you just want the '1' printed three times. Instead of your incrementing statement being `i+=3`, you probably want it to be `i++`. And for the comparison, you want `i<3`, not `i<message.length`. So this is probably what you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){ //go through the loop three times. Print 1 in the loop only if a>m.
    if(a>m){
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}
```

See the syntax on the [for loop here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

It executes the third statement every time through the loop, so with `i` initialized to 0 and the statement `i+=3` at the end, the first time you go through the loop `i` will be `0`, next time it will be `3`, then `6`, then `9`, etc. until your condition becomes false (as you've written it, it will go until `i>=message.length`, so if `message.length` was 3, you would only go through the loop one time as you've written your code).

Answer (score 0):

This means you want to **break** out of the loop. There's 2 main ways to do that:

### Using the `break` keyword:

Java includes a [keyword for breaking out of loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) as well as [keyword for skipping certain parts of loops.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) If you want to break out of the loop if a certain term applies - you can just use it - `break;` - it will stop the loop on the spot. Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<message.length; i+=3){
 if(a>m){
  System.out.println("1");
  break; // you go out of the loop-
  }
}
// and the code goes on from here.
```

### Using a flag:

You can use a boolean value to track how the loop goes each time in the term part. This way, you can track it and go out of the loop if you need to. Example:

```
Boolean myFlag = true;
for(int i = 0; i<message.length && myFlag ; i+=3){ // notice how the term changed.
 if(a>m){
  System.out.println("1");
  myFlag = false; // The term will no longer fullfill and you will go out of the loop.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an index and a while loop like this. Everytime the if statement hits its counted by I. When the if statement hits 3 times the loop stops...

```
int i = 0

while(i < 3){
if(a>m){
    System.out.println("1");
    i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      if(a > m){
         // 1 will be printed for 3 times and no more provided 'a > m'
         System.out.println("1");
      } else {
         break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<message.length; i+=3) {
  if(a>m) {
    System.out.println("1");
    count++;
    if(count == 3)
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
int count1 =0, count2=0, count3=0;

for(int i = 0; i<message.length; i+=3){
  if(a>m){
    System.out.println("1");

    if(count1==0){
       count1++;
       count2=0;
       count3=0;
    }

    else if(count1==1){
       count2++;
       count3=0;
    }

    else if(count1==1 && count2==1){
       count3++;
    } 

    else{
       count1=0;
       count2=0;
       count3=0;

    }





  }

 if(count1==1 && count2 ==1 && count3==1){
    break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter variable that increments is `a > m` and resets otherwise

```
int ctr = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
    ctr = a > m ? ctr + 1 : 0;
    if (ctr == 3) break;        
}
```

Just curious to know how are `a` and `m` getting modified, they have to modified inside that loop, otherwise this code doesn't make any sense

Answer (score -1):

There are also options that don't involve loops. Maybe not as pretty, but they may be easier to understand if you don't have much experience with loops.

```
if(a>m){
    System.out.println("111");
  }
```

or

```
if(a>m){
    System.out.println("1" + "\n" + "1" + "\n" + "1");
  }
```

or

```
 if(a>m){
    System.out.println("1");
    System.out.println("1");
    System.out.println("1");
  }
```

It kind of depends on what requirements you have to meet.